# How to stop timestamp updating when column is edited after first edit

Tags: google-sheets

I have a code that puts a timestamp in when column 1 is edited and then a second timestamp when another column has the word 'collected' input to it. From this I then work out time it took to be collected and use that data. However if someone edits column 1 again it updates the timestamp so I'm looking for a script to allow it to only do it on first edit. Here is my current script;

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
if( sheet.getName() == "CC sheet" ) {
  //Update timestamp when changed to collected

  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  Logger.log(range.getColumn())
  if( range.getColumn() == 7.0 ) { //if we are in the status column...
    var nextCell = range.offset(0, 2);
     if(range.getValue() == 'Collected')   
       if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
          nextCell.setValue(new Date());
  }
//end
}


if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'CC sheet' || e.range.columnStart !== 1) return;
e.range.offset(0, 5).setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null);
 }
```

It is the bottom bit I need to change to only update on first edit. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace last row or code with this one:

```
if (e.range.offset(0, 5).getValue() === '') {

   e.range.offset(0, 5).setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null);

}
```

it's the same 'is empty?' check, as you have in the first part of script.